# ajax validation not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, validation

Jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('input.textinput3').each(function() {

                $(this).rules("add", 
                    {
                        required: true,                     
                        minlength: 3,
                        remote: "report/user_check.php",

                        messages: {
                            required: "Type Serial number!",                            
                            minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} character are necessary"),
                            remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already taken"),
                            // remote: 'This email address has already been used'

                        }
                    })
            });  
// initialize the validator
        $('form.warregform').validate();    

});
```

My PHP files

```
include("db.class1.php");

if (isset($_POST['wproserial'])) {  
    $db = new mysqldb();
    $db->select_db();

    for ( $i=0;$i<count($_POST['wproserial']);$i++) {
        {           
            $wproserial = $_POST['wproserial'][$i];             
        }   
    }

    $query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE SerailNo='mysql_real_escape_string($wproserial)')";

    if($db->num_rows($db->query($query)) < 1) {
       return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

I can't check validation with existing database, this serial no. is already register or not. every input data is showing message "is already taken". so i can't submit. My Serial no input field is unlimited.

My Html files

```
default show
<input name="wproserial[]" id="wproserial0" type="text" value="" class="textinput3 " autocomplete="off">
After Add
<input name="wproserial[]'+i+'" id="wproserial'+i+'" type="text" value="" class="textinput3">
```

Comment: SELECT EXISTS is always going to return a row, you need to rethink the query or the if

Comment: And the query is broken, you cannot have the php function `mysql_real_escape_String` inside the sql without escaping it, it will literally end up as `SELECT ... 'mysql_real_escape_String()'...`

Comment: As always: `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated, the entire `mysql_*` extension is deprecated, and will be removed. The deprecation process has been going on for years. PHP's doc pages have a _big red warning_ box on the functions pages that tell you _not_ to use the functions anymore. Just **RTFM**

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve, but it doesn't make sense to me that you loop through all serial keys, just to check the last serial key against the database. What does `report/user_check.php` echo? Why are you using `return`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your query

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE SerailNo='mysql_real_escape_string($wproserial)')";
```

to this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE SerailNo='".mysql_real_escape_string($wproserial)."'";
```

Comment: There's a rogue `)` at the end of your query, but otherwise this is the right solution.

Comment: yes, i also remove  )  .. i don't know why my function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The remote validation expects your server side script to return json.  You should do the following instead of just returning `true` or `false` :

```
if($db->num_rows($db->query($query)) < 1) {
    $valid = 'true';
} else {
    $valid = 'false';
}

echo json_encode($valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE SerailNo='".mysql_real_escape_string($wproserial)."')";
```

instead

```
$query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE SerailNo='mysql_real_escape_string($wproserial)')";
```